# SSRS Grouping columns to show minimum amount of columns

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to group a report by rows and columns which is working fine.

I would like to show at minimum (as an example) 5 columns and possibly more depending on the group.

Is there a way to set a minimum of columns that are shown on the report?
Further, can i define a width such as 20cm or 8 inches and have the columns adapt their width equally across that range?

Answer (score 0):

How many columns are shown on the report will depend on your data.  If your query isn't returning five distinct values, you won't get five columns.  One trick you can use is to add dummy records to your query using UNION until you have enough distinct values.  For example:

```
SELECT MonthName, Amount FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JAN' AS MonthName, 0 AS Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FEB' AS MonthName, 0 AS Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MAR' AS MonthName, 0 AS Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 'APR' AS MonthName, 0 AS Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MAY' AS MonthName, 0 AS Amount
```

Maybe Table1 will give you some or all of these Months, also.  But now you know your result set will contain at least enough distinct MonthNames to provide you with five columns.  You also have to be careful to make sure that your dummy records don't interfere with the main work of the report, such as summing up the total Amount.

You asked a separate question about column widths.  Try looking for an "Expression" where you can set the column width.  You will need to know how many columns your data is currently returning.  The SQL can get complicated but one way to do it might be to put the query into a CTE (Common Table Expression) and then also return COUNT(DISTINCT MonthName) as MonthColumnCount.  You would use the (First value of) MonthColumnCount to calculate the desired column width.  It is possible this might cost more effort than it is worth to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thx I will see how far i can get with this :)

In my example I have to report the amount of hours that were registered based on the week and functions.

Where my weeks are the rows and the functions are the columns, the problem is I don't know how many people with different functions registered hours in that specific month/week/year/... :).

Comment: I would try adding dummy records with zero hours for each of the weeks and functions you want to be sure to see on the report.  Good luck!